# enable and disable textfield in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need solution how to enable and disable text field using jquery when document is ready.
Sample code which i tried is  as follows, but am not getting any output nor alert are getting displayed.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     /*jQuery('#tan label.control input').change();*/
});
jQuery("#cca label.control input").on('change', function (event) {
  alert('I am pretty sure the text box changed');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: can u share your HTML code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery("#cca label.control input").on('change', function (e) {
    alert('I am pretty sure the text box changed');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

If that doesn't work then please respond with what your console returns when you type `jQuery("#cca label.control input").length`

Comment: am getting this error andy in console "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. "

Comment: Please try my edited answer. What version of jQuery are you using?